# What's the use of WPF's DataBinding?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I know the whole point behind it, but at the end of the day, the only thing provided is a clean code, am I right?

The problem:

To perform a data bind, you'll have to do some stuff in code behind (set a dependency property), which sometimes may be clear, and sometimes not. Then you'll have to find out how the hell to access the values from your dependency property (the object you're trying to use). Then, ok, you spent some time deciding that you'll access it through ElementName or Ancestor or whatever (because you'll have to find out by yourself how this works, Microsoft's documentation on that is pretty lame, it's not straight forward).

Then, ok, you spent some time and now your data binding is working, except that is not. Because the class of the object you're binding to must implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Just that. Or not, because you'll have to assure that an event (`OnPropertyChanged`) must be triggered in order to update the values on your interface ... by sending as an argument a string containing THE NAME OF THE EFFING PROPERTY. That's as lame as JSF's way to access values (obliging the developer to have getters and setters exactly the way they want). An also, if you're building your software in layers, forget, you'll have to implement INotifyPropertyChange every-effing-where.

I'm writing this because I want to know if:

- I'm doing everything wrong and that's why I don't get the point.
- Is there a better solution to deal with this kind of stuff?
- Am I the only one who thinks that it doesn't make any sense?

Before anyone asks: Yes, I understand that the event makes "some" sense, because there must be a way to know that the object changed. But I don't see much difference of using that or just calling an `Update` method every time I do anything in the interface. I hope you guys don't think I'm stupid for posting this ... I'm a pretty new programmer (3 years since my graduation began and 2 years working experience), but the lack of a better way to do that kind of stuff doesn't look like, for instance, Microsoft's ASP.NET MVC, which just works magically. I'm not asking for everything to be easy, just asking for a better documentation, and, I don't know, an easier (by easier I mean more straight-forward) way to do something that you're supposed to do when using the framework, something that is considered elegant.

Comment: I'll be downvoted by many, but I think I have a point.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't about making points (expect when we are talking about rep, it's all about that).

Comment: I think the key word here is `magically`. Databinding is not a magic. It was done using the framework, as you could do it on your own. That's why you have `INotifyPropertyChanged` with property names - this is the only legal way to do it in .Net. Without any magic. WinForms also had some binding stuff but it was magic, I've seen developers who said that it just works, without `INotifyPropertyChanged` but they don't know how it works. In WPF it is done in correct - using the .Net framework, not using some tricks in order to make you happy in **some** cases

Comment: @H.B. Well, you can see that I wasn't only trying to make a point. I asked two "real" questions there.

Comment: @Snowbear I understend your point and agree, but the problem is: documentation is not straight-forward. I also asked if the problem was me, when I asked if I was doing everythin wrong. I have a software which has two layers: one to business logic and another to GUI, which is WPF. Some of the models of my logic must be "prepared" to be displayed, which is why I created a viewmodel to them, but in order to use it, I must go down to my business logic, implement the interface, then on my viewmodel, which is simply a container for calculated values, propagate the event.

Comment: I'll simply just vote to close the question, because it seems to offend more than to propose a discussion on something that could be improved. I love WPF, I really do. There's a lot of stuff that are great, I love using XAML to design interfaces, but DataBinding doesn't seem to fit with all.

Comment: @slugster Thanks, your comment really adds something to the conversation.

Comment: @Bruno, I was actually halfway through typing a constructive answer when the question got closed. If you figure out a way to reword your question, then edit it, it may get reopened.

Answer (score 2):

1. That it is hard to learn does not change that it is a powerful technique, this covers about most of your rant.
2. You can resolve the property name from a lambda expression if you have an aversion to strings. The code for an extension method that does that is floating around somewhere on SO.
3. If you don't want to implement it everywhere implement it in one base-class.
4. If you want magic use an MVVM framework that does that. Caliburn for example hooks up controls and methods/properties without writing any binding code.
5. Bindings decouple components.

Comment: My "rant" (understand, that was not supposed do be that way, I was trying to see if I was missing some really big point) is not that it is hard to learn: is that the documentations doesn't help that much. If you're not using the MVM pattern (which I understand is suposed to be used), the thing simply doesn't seem to found it's way to an elegant code.

Comment: @Bruno: I think the code is very elegant and i find the documentation to be very helpful as well. Jusdging from the questions i am presented here on a regular basis it just seems like most people don't even care to read it as it addresses most of those questions.

Comment: I've followed some number of tutorials, bought an ebook, read the things related to the matter, but I still don't see most of the point. I'll read more, then, and see if I can learn it well. But, still, I think I was trying to show a POV in the matter and you just got mad about it, didn't quite try to understand what I was trying to say. But thanks for your comments and responses anyway, you helped me by showing some ways and giving some advice.

Comment: @Bruno: Where did i get mad? How can you tell if i tried to understand what you were saying? You are just making assumptions here, which are wrong. That aside, isn't it obvious that data-binding is great? Haven't you ever written any code which does have no "magic" and no binding? You always need to change properties manually and keep everything synchronized, it's the horror.

Comment: That's exactly the point, apart from clean code, I really don't see too much of a difference. I'm trying, in the comments, to apologize if I was stupid, and also to understand how that was supposed to work. You read my question and you know I made my homework by reading documentation and tutorials, because if I did not, I wouldn't be able to write how to perform it, am I right? But by magically, I meant what happens to routing in ASP.NET MVC, something to works right out of the box, but that you can also change.

Comment: @Bruno: Clean code is one of the most important things there is because it prevents errors, it's not only clean but also shorter and more expressive, it has a lot of such positive attributes. I know what you meant by magic, but `data-binding != routing`, some things just have a limit of how simple they can get, and data-binding when done right is very simple.

Comment: Okay, I get it. I'm reading another tutorial right now to see if it fits to my problem better than the last one. And I agree when you talk about clean code ... but if the methods are separated, then it is possible to have a clean (different looking) code that does exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

I like turtles. I also love data binding. I recommend reading up on the MVVM pattern... it uses data binding to make it easy for you to run unit tests and keep your code organized/clean. Be sure to look at how the "DataContext" property is used in MVVM.

P.S. I don't think that using the name of the effing property in OnNotifyProperty is lame at all. What else would you use without adding dependencies or unneeded complexity?

P.P.S. Clean code is a very big effing deal.

Comment: Agreed and agreed. You understand, I was not trying to make do a rage post, and if some interpreted as that, I'm sorry. I shouldn't use the word lame ... but in comparison to ASP.NET MVC: routing works "magically" if you want, but if you want something more complex, you'll have to learn how to deal with it. DataBinding, IMHO, should work like that.

Comment: IMO, databinding works quite "magically" if you use it right. I initially read about databinding in a WPF book that didn't get into MVVM and pretty much only explained how to bind to static properties. I thought it was pretty lame... until I learned to set the datacontext once and then bind to as many variables as needed. I  got hooked on WPF once I got it. The MVVM pattern is also great for unit testing.

Comment: You see, that is exactly the kind of thing I wished as an answer! The source of this book, for instance ... how to do things right. Because as I google the subject, I see many different aproaches (which is good), but none that helps totally.